# How to use String subsequence method in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to use String's subsequence method in blackberry which is given in java API but not present in Blackberry API. Here is the method :

```
String.subSequence(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

I want to use that method so how should it be possible if I cant access that API. Can u please post the code/url with code/api in Blackberry which will perform same function like subsequence method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java SE's `subSequence` is implemented in java.lang.String just because String was made to implement `CharSequence` interface. If you read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence%28int,%20int%29), it says:

> *An invocation of this method of the form
>        str.subSequence(begin, end)
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>        str.substring(begin, end)
>   This method is defined so that the String class can implement the CharSequence interface.*

So in BlackBerry, as there's no `CharSequence` interface because it was introduced in Java 1.4, you can use `substring` instead with identical result.